# Extracting first value from series of grouped variables in R to calculate travel time

Tags: r

I've written code to calculate travel times for a small tagged population of fish.  My dataframe `d` of each fish's "path" looks like this:

```
  TagID  Station  arrival           departure
1  2051   I80_1 2012-04-04 20:20:04 2012-04-04 20:35:04
2  2051  Lisbon 2012-04-05 09:06:18 2012-04-05 09:11:36
3  2051    Rstr 2012-04-05 18:46:34 2012-04-05 19:03:21
4  2051    Rstr 2012-04-05 22:31:59 2012-04-05 22:51:09
5  2051    Rstr 2012-04-06 02:30:31 2012-04-06 02:54:01
6  2051 Base_TD 2012-04-06 06:52:39 2012-04-06 08:24:11
```

My code extracts the final arrival time for each fish's final Station (in the snippet above, for example, it would be `2012-04-06 06:52:39` at Station `Base_TD`).

Once I've isolated that final arrival time, I summarize `ttime` as the total time elapsed from `releasetime` (a preset value) for each fish, as well as the final station location for each fish.   I've accomplished this using `dplyr` on the whole dataset with the following pipeline, but `dplyr` was the only way I knew to do this task, and I'm worried that I'm propagating invisible errors with all the grouping and ungrouping.  Is that a valid concern?  How would I write equivalent code in base R to make sure I get the same results?

```
releasetime <- as.POSIXct('2012-03-30 18:00:00', tz = 'Pacific/Pitcairn')
releasetime <- lubridate::with_tz(releasetime, tzone = 'UTC')

tt <- d %>% 
  group_by(TagID, Station) %>% 
  arrange(arrival) %>% 
  slice(row_number() == 1) %>%  # cuts df down to first detection of fish at each station
  ungroup() %>% 
  group_by(TagID) %>% # get back up to full path level
  arrange(arrival) %>%  #arrange path by arrival time
  summarise(ttime = last(arrival) - releasetime,
         laststation = Station[arrival ==last(arrival)]) # now the last arrival should be the only arrival at the last station; summarize travel time for each fish.
```

If you'd like a sample dataset to use, here's a `dput()` of three different individuals' tracks:

```
d <- structure(list(TagID = c(2059L, 2059L, 2059L, 2059L, 2059L, 2059L, 
2059L, 2059L, 2059L, 2059L, 2059L, 2062L, 2062L, 2062L, 2062L, 
2062L, 2062L, 2062L, 2062L, 2062L, 2062L, 2066L, 2066L, 2066L, 
2066L, 2066L, 2066L, 2066L, 2066L, 2066L, 2066L, 2066L, 2066L, 
2066L), Station = c("I80_1", "Lisbon", "Rstr", "Rstr", "Base_TD", 
"BCE", "MAE", "MAW", "MAW", "MAE", "MAE", "I80_1", "Lisbon", 
"Rstr", "Base_TD", "BCE", "BCE", "BCE", "BCE", "BCE", "BCE", 
"I80_1", "Lisbon", "Rstr", "BCE", "BCE", "BCE", "MAE", "MAW", 
"MAW", "MAE", "MAE", "MAW", "MAE"), arrival = structure(c(1333451872, 
1333562100, 1333607351, 1333626207, 1333642897, 1333725713, 1334092156, 
1334092450, 1334102208, 1334102426, 1334169836, 1333232026, 1333301118, 
1333364285, 1333383477, 1333729987, 1333746859, 1333788503, 1333844040, 
1333857104, 1333884034, 1333184935, 1333229762, 1333270977, 1333503027, 
1333533868, 1333542226, 1333822681, 1333823087, 1333832661, 1333832863, 
1333861226, 1333861662, 1333877063), class = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt"
), tzone = "UTC"), departure = structure(c(1333452194, 1333562472, 
1333608264, 1333626844, 1333643196, 1333725773, 1334092599, 1334093077, 
1334102905, 1334103169, 1334169868, 1333232307, 1333301776, 1333366712, 
1333385467, 1333730036, 1333746859, 1333788634, 1333844585, 1333857123, 
1333884226, 1333185124, 1333230300, 1333272832, 1333503224, 1333535705, 
1333542296, 1333823638, 1333824235, 1333832964, 1333833171, 1333861898, 
1333862298, 1333877179), class = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt"), tzone = "UTC")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-34L), .Names = c("TagID", "Station", "arrival", "departure"))
```

For which the correct output should be:

```
TagID ttime          laststation
 2059 10.801505 days         MAW
 2062  6.606331 days         BCE
 2066  7.683877 days         MAW
```

Thanks very much for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
do.call(rbind,
    lapply(split(d, d$TagID), function(a){ #split by 'TagID' and loop over sub-groups
        a = a[!duplicated(a$Station),] #Retain only the first appearances of 'arrival'
        a = a[order(a$arrival),] #Sort each sub-group by 'arrival'
        cbind(TagID = a$TagID[1], #obtain TagID, station, and ttime of the sub-group,
            Last_Station = a$Station[NROW(a)],
            ttime = (as.numeric(as.POSIXct(a$arrival[NROW(a)])) - as.numeric(releasetime))/(60*60*24))
        }
        )
        )
#     TagID  Last_Station ttime             
#[1,] "2059" "MAW"        "10.8015046296296"
#[2,] "2062" "BCE"        "6.60633101851852"
#[3,] "2066" "MAW"        "7.68387731481481"
```

Comment: quick question: how do I know that `a = a[!duplicated(a$Station),]` won't get rid of the row with the arrival that I need?  How does `duplicated` decide which rows to keep and which to remove?  I read the documentation but I still don't understand, I apologize.

Comment: `duplicated` doesn't mark the first appearance as `TRUE`. It marks `TRUE` only after second appearance (Run `duplicated(c(2,2,3))`). So, it shouldn't get rid of the arrival that you need.

Comment: think I've got it - so if for some reason I needed to extract the second-to-last arrival or some index other than the first one, `duplicated` would not be the way to go, but it works for this particular problem.  Thanks!

Comment: @Von, right. If the requirement was different and I was still going with this approach, I might have attempted combining `duplicated` with `head` and `tail` or something like that.

Answer (score 1):

We can try with `split` from `base R`

```
r1 <- do.call(rbind, lapply(split(d, list(d$TagID, d$Station),
       drop = TRUE), function(x) head(x[order(x$arrival),],1)))
r2 <- do.call(rbind, lapply(split(r1, r1$TagID), function(x) {
     x1 <- x[order(x$arrival),]
     data.frame(TagID = x1$TagID[1], 
                ttime = x1$arrival[nrow(x1)] - releasetime, 
                laststation = x1$Station[x1$arrival == x1$arrival[nrow(x1)]])}))

row.names(r2) <- NULL
r2
#  TagID          ttime laststation
#1  2059 10.801505 days         MAW
#2  2062  6.606331 days         BCE  
#3  2066  7.683877 days         MAW
```

Comment: This solution works as well - I selected d.b's answer above for being slightly more concise, but both methods made good tests for the `dplyr` pipeline.  Thanks!

Comment: @Von Thank you for the comments.  No problem with your selection.  My solution returns different class for the columns